# R 3.1.2 library file

Tags: r, swig

I need to link to R library and have seen some pointers on the Web - all referencing `Rdll.lib` file.

However, in my installation directory `\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64` contains only DLL file - R.dll.

Does the default installation of R ships a library and if yes, where to find it?

As a note, this all relates to attempts to create an R wrapper for C++ library with SWIG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually build the `Rdll.lib`. Instruction can be found in `R` folder in the `doc/README.packages` (at least for my 3.1.3 `R` installation):

> First build the import library Rdll.lib by (from the sources)
>
> ```
> make R.exp
> lib /def:R.exp /out:Rdll.lib
> ```
>
> or, depending on your version of VC++:
>
> ```
> link /lib /def:R.exp /machine:x86 /out:Rdll.lib
> ```

Comment: I see... Thanks. Can you please explain how to create .exp file? I downloaded R source code but a bit confused on how to create the file with exports

Comment: @OlegShirokikh I'm not very sure, but with [`RTools`](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), it was compiled by default with `./configure` and `make`. But as I see from the question, it will be more useful to use [`RCpp`](http://www.rcpp.org/) to wrap the library.